# traefik2 in docker swarm with Windows container for windows server 2019. "chmod acme.json: not supported by windows"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

**Error Message**

```
level=error msg="Unable to add ACME provider to the providers list: unable to get ACME account: chmod acme.json: not supported by windows"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.1.2-windowsservercore-1809
    command:
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.swarmMode=true
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine
      - --api
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.email={myemail}
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.storage=acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true
      # - --certificatesResolvers.leresolver.acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=web
#      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    volumes:
      - ".:c:/letsencrypt/:rw"
      - type: npipe
        source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
    labels:
      # Dashboard
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.dev.local`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=authtraefik"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.authtraefik.basicauth.users=admin:$$2y$$05$$XNAg2G17qyZ9Aygh7GeHWOjOlIamg94ZhQxRTHcY0E9cIsEps/O9y" # user/password

      # global redirect to https
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"

      # middleware redirect
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"

  my-app:
    image: sixeyed/whoami-dotnet:3.0
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app.rule=Host(`traefik.dev.local`)"
      # - "traefik.http.services.my-app.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app.tls.certresolver=leresolver"

volumes:
  traefik-certificates:
#   external: true
networks:
  traefik-public:
#   external: true
```

Log message:

```
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:15:35+01:00" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{},\"tcp\":{}}" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:15:35+01:00" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider docker" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:15:50+01:00" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{},\"tcp\":{}}" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:15:50+01:00" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider docker" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:16:05+01:00" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{},\"tcp\":{}}" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:16:05+01:00" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider docker" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:16:20+01:00" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{},\"tcp\":{}}" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:16:20+01:00" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider docker" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:16:35+01:00" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{},\"tcp\":{}}" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:16:35+01:00" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider docker" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:16:50+01:00" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{},\"tcp\":{}}" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:16:50+01:00" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider docker" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2020-01-21T17:17:05+01:00" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{},\"tcp\":{}}" providerName=docker
```

**Currently, all the route including "traefik.dev.local" goes to "404 page not found".**

Any help is greatly appreciated.